# Transferring a text file from android device to pc via USB

Tags: android, usb, transfer

I'm working on a project which will compile user input data over a course of time and then will be reviewed by a third party. At current my intention was simply to have the users visit the third party, hook their device up via USB and send the data via a command from the device. The more I look into it this seems like it cannot be done so I was just looking for some clarity on the matter.

Can android devices push files onto PC at the behest of an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is prohibited. The only way around is to have an application on the PC site that manage this. One tip, don't bother around with the MTP stuff. Just write a WebService for your third party and enable the user to upload its data there.